# Can decorators be a direct child of the component?

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

Looking at the Decorator pattern page on wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), the layout looks something like this:

- Component interface
- Component implementation
- Decorator interface that implements the component interface
- Decorator(s) that implement the decorator interface

Can decorators instead directly implement the component interface (and skip on the decorator interface)?

Comment: Which programming language is this question about?

Comment: This should be applicable to any language that supports inheritance or interfaces. Why do you ask?

Comment: @neverendingqs there is no decorator interface, there is an optional _abstract_ decorator.

Comment: @qujck aren't interfaces pure abstract classes (functionally anyways)? Why does it have to be an abstract decorator?

Comment: @qujck also I think you answered the question =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main benefit you get with the Decorator Pattern is that, for client code, it's transparent.  They don't need to know about the decorator, they can just treat it like a plain old concrete implementation of the base interface:

```
ThingDoer thingDoer = new ThingDoerDecorator(new AwesomeThingDoer());
ThingDoer otherThingDoer = new AwesomeThingDoer();

thingDoer.doThing();
otherThingDoer.doThing();
```

**This is only possible because the decorator implements the same interface as the thing it's decorating.**  If it doesn't implement this interface you lose most of the power of this pattern.

However, sometimes it makes sense to have a **base decorator implementation**.

```
abstract class BaseThingDoerDecorator implements ThingDoer {
    private ThingDoer thingDoer;

    protected BaseDecorator(ThingDoer thingDoer) {
        this.thingDoer = thingDoer;
    }

    @Override
    public void doThing() {
        thingDoer.doThing();
    }
}
```

Now it becomes practical to do things like this:

```
ThingDoer thingDoer = new BaseThingDoerDecorator(new AwesomeThingDoer()) {
    @Override
    public void doThing() {
        System.out.println("This is an anonymous decorator");
        super.doThing();
    }
};
```

Or maybe you want all of your decorators to be shielded from exceptions in the base component:

```
abstract class BaseThingDoerDecorator implements ThingDoer {
    // Same as above...
    // ...
    @Override
    public void doThing() {
        try {
            thingDoer.doThing();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify @Floegipoky, is the answer: "Yes, decorators be a direct child of the component. However, here are some examples where you want to use an abstract class."?

Comment: @neverendingqs No, my answer is that the decorators must *implement* the component interface, but here are some examples where it makes sense for them to *inherit* from a base class as well.

Comment: hmm that's what I meant to say, but my grammar and wording wasn't the best in this question. Anyways, your response clarifies what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the UML diagram from the wikipedia page you cited:

[image: Decorator pattern in UML]

In this diagram, Decorator is *not* an interface, but an abstract class. Component is also *not* an interface in this diagram (since the ConcreteComponent and *Decorator* classes inheriting from it don't have dashed lines from the arrow in the diagram). I know it's a detail, but UML is specific for a reason.

That said, any ConcreteDecorator could inherit directly from Component (or implement its interface if your design uses an interface) without using a *Decorator* abstract class. However, *all* ConcreteDecorators need to aggregate a component, so the abstract class might be useful to avoid duplicated code if you have more than one ConcreteDecorator.

Comment: I'd actually argue that the diagram is wrong.  If the pattern was implemented in this fashion, each decorator would have 2 components.  The only way to avoid needless overhead would be to make the base component (the one that the decorator "is") completely empty- which makes it an interface in everything but the name.  This may be an effective way to crowbar it into languages that don't have interfaces, but it's misleading and certainly shouldn't be used for the authoritative model of the pattern.

Comment: I only see one component @Floegipoky. Where is the second one?

Comment: Decorators "wrap" components, so I don't see how an interface makes sense in the place of a Decorator. The design here looks like the one from the GoF, which was suggested before interfaces in Java or C# existed. Please cite your authoritative reference, @Floegipoky

Comment: According to this diagram, each decorator has the component that it aggregates (the one it's wrapping) and one that it gets as a result of inheritance.  If the base component holds any sort of state, each component will hold 2 copies.

Comment: Ok, so you're counting inheritance ("is a") and aggregation ("has a"). Java's java.io classes use Decorator this way, e.g., BufferedInputStream and LineNumberInputStream both extend FilterInputStream, which acts as the abstract decorator class. They are all subclasses of the abstract class [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html). Theoretically there could be duplicated state, but I'd say it's worth it for the benefit of the pattern. Of course, I'm assuming the Liskov Substitution Principle is respected.

Comment: I was using "interface" and "abstract class" interchangeably, since interfaces are functionally pure abstract classes. However, I now see how partially implemented abstract classes can reduce code duplication from @Floegipoky's example in his answer.